# SignTool.exe Sporadically Fails with Exit Code 1

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, digital-certificate, signtool

As part of our build system, we use signtool.exe with a certificate to sign our binaries once they've been built. Occasionally (it's hard to tell when it will strike), the signing fails:

```
 error MSB3073: The command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\bin\signtool.exe" [...] exited with code 1.
```

According to the MSDN, an exit code of 1 means that there was an error signing the file. I can verify that the file didn't get signed.

I've also noticed that occasionally, the timestamp portion times out with a different error message, albeit that the file still gets signed (without the timestamp).

How can I troubleshoot and fix these seemingly random, inconsistent signature failures?

Comment: I have the same experience: signtool occasionally fails during timestamping. There seems to be no solution other than re-run signtool.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp some people report updating their Windows XP certificates works, and some other weird stuff like that. I want a definitive answer, since a failed build is very serious for me. But I fear you are right.

Comment: Suppose your timestamping server is completely unreachable (network cable unplugged etc). How would signtool or other tool for the same purpose be able to deal with this? Of course, I wish signtool were more tolerant to failures and tried to perform timestamping once again, but you must be ready for possible timestamping failure anyway.

Comment: True. Maybe the answer is to address this at a higher level, such as on the continuous integration server. I'm still hoping for a lower-level solution though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly suspect a failing connection to the timestamp server being responsible for occasional failures. Perhaps you check your system event log for lost connections at the time in question.

Comment: If this is the case, how would I rectify this? I don't control the timestamp server.

Comment: Could be almost anything. Check your infrastructure. We once had an issue with a defective network cable. That was easy. Might be local downtime due to maintenance. Might  be a problem with your Internet provider. My advice (just as Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp explained): Implement a retry mechanism. Don't let assembly signing be a time critical part of your process.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to mention that the build process should be more robust? That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Hmm, my version of `signtool` does **not** give a failure exit code when timestamping fails. In fact it pretends everything is fine, which is a *major* annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It happens because MS antimalware process MsMpEng.exe check the binary and don't let anyone access it.
To solve the problem, I build binary on RAM disk and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I've just into this issue, on Windows 8.1, so it's not the Windows XP root certificates issue that some folks cite.

I found that the problem was caused because the .exe being signed was also running.

If you run signtool from the cmd prompt and try to sign it you will get a helpful text message telling you what is wrong (so much better than the return code 1 from CreateProcess().

Stopped the running process and was able to sign OK.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the .pfx file in the solution was an old one. Until someone told me to replace the certificate file with the new, valid one, I continued to get "Fails with Exit Code 1" error.

Meaning, make sure that the certificate file is valid and not expired.

Answer (score 0):

SignTool.exe has a `/v` switch (verbose) which can help you diagnose the problem.