# InnoSetup - while compiling sign tool failed with exit code 0x1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, inno-setup

Its failing to compile in signing.

In my innosetup packaging i have to include some third party software such as VLC, Google Chrome, Putty, etc etc.

The moment those third party tools are included compile/build is failing. But when i do not use them its compiling well. (unfortunately i cant use those apps via external URL so i must need to embed them in my compile)

```
Source: "C:\Users\tpt\Desktop\innosetup\nw\run.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\tpt\Desktop\innosetup\software\*"; DestDir: "{app}\software"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

[image]

EDIT: i zip the software folder but still same, also i zip .exe into .rar but still same error?

[image]

Comment: I tried to do the software folder as software.rar or zip but still same error. How can i fix it please?

Comment: All works, but when i use chrome64.rar (which is Google Chrome standalone) then the compile, signtool all fails.

Comment: try to remove timestamp from commandline, you might having [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9383287/1254172) issue

Comment: I'd suspect that too, but it's just a wild guess. It can be anything since we cannot see the command line that is being executed.

Comment: So i do this you mean? Before: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /f C:\Users\tpt\Desktop\innosetup\OSxxxx.pfx /p Mypass /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll $f` After: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /f C:\Users\tpt\Desktop\innosetup\OSxxxx.pfx /p Mypass` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the extension from rarfile, make it to just "chrome64", with a batch script rename it while setup the files.

In innosetup

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\rename.bat"
```

In rename.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
ren Chrome64 Chrome64.rar
del rename.bat
```

I'm just removed the extension from Chrome.exe, and with batch rename it back to exe while installing, and after rename, its run without problem.
Compile didn't give me error.

Comment: Why the people tend to use batch files when they have so strong support of Pascal Script I never understand.